# Need help to create a custom filed in SharePoint 2013 List

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

Need help for below scenario in SharePoint 2013 list:

Requirement:

There is some training which happens every month. That trainer has maximum capacity of 25 for each month.

So I have created a SharePoint List which has a field called “Month” which is a Dropdown with values like `Jan`, `Feb`, `Mar` and so on.

So if for a particular month, the capacity is already 25, then that month should be disabled from the “Month” Dropdown field.
Say for example, `Jan` will be enabled in the “Month” Dropdown for 25 submissions, and once 25 forms are submitted, `Jan` will be disabled from the list form.

Can someone please help on how to achieve this? It’s urgent.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

On "NewForm.aspx" insert contentpane with javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clientContext = null;
    var web = null;
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Initialize, "sp.js");
    function Initialize()
    {
        clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        web = clientContext.get_web();
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("enter_list_name");
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        var q = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' /></OrderBy></Query>";
        camlQuery.set_viewXml(q);
        this.listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.load(listItems, 'Include(Id)');
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListItemsLoadSuccess), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }
    function onListItemsLoadSuccess(sender, args) {
        var count = 0;
        var count = this.listItems.get_count();
if(count >= 25)
        {
alert('the list i complete...');
window.location.href = https://redirectURL link;
    }
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
</script>
```

Note that you will have to do some adjustments to the code above, to fit your specific detailes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JQuery Script to hide the options in the choice column with the relevant count number.

More information:

[How to disable particular item in a drop down element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840200/how-to-disable-particular-item-in-a-drop-down-element)
and 
[counting occurrences in a Sharepoint column](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/07c11126-cb3a-47dd-a43e-786576acdf06/javascript-sample-for-counting-occurrences-in-a-sharepoint-column?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)